# How to call a function from binary data

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have some binary data which contains a bunch of functions and want to call one of it.
I know the signature of these functions along with the offset relative to the start of the file. Calling convention is the default one: `__cdecl`.
The file was already loaded into a memory page with executing permissions.

For example (`A`, `B`, `C` being some types)

```
void myFunction (A *arg1, B arg2, C arg3); // Signature
int myOffset = 0x42; // Offset
```

How can I specify that `myOffset` points to `myFunction`?

Comment: I am not an expert, but i think if you call a __cdecl function, the stack will leak if your program is expecting __stdcall. The default should be __stdcall

Comment: __stdcall is used for WINAPI functions. __cdecl is the standard for other functions. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Etan  I  have similar problem, wondering how did you get offset of all routines ... please help!

Comment: @Dhara Darji: For example, you can perform a pattern-scan for a routine's payload. To answer your question more precisely you need to provide more context.

Comment: @Etan thanks ... I found that in my definition .. sorry didnt look at that before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// define a function pointer
typedef __cdecl void (*your_function) (A *arg1, B arg2, C arg3); 
your_function ftr;

char * memory = 0x123456; // base segment address

fptr = (your_function)(memory + 0x42); //calculate memory address

(*ftpr)(a,b,b); // call function
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not quite sure what you are asking. I assume that you try to declare a function pointer, and assign a function pointer to some arbitrary address.

To declare a function pointer,

```
void (*p)(A*,B,C);
```

To assign it,

```
p = (void (*)(A*,B,C)))0x42;
```

To call the function,

```
p(a,b,c) or (*p)(a,b,c);
```

Answer (score 3):

For the question itself: you simply need to add the address in memory you loaded the binary to. I.e. if you loaded the binary to address `myLoadAddress` just add that to `myOffset`. This won't enable you to easily call the function, however. If you want to do that, you should treat it like a library file (and if it in fact is a library file check for a system function for loading libraries like [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx) on Windows, then use [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28VS.85%29.aspx) to retrieve a pointer to the function).

```
// create a type for your function signature
typedef void (*myFunc)(A *arg1, B arg2, C arg3);
// create a pointer to your function
myFunc myFuncPointer;
// set the address of the function in memory
myFuncPointer = myLoadAddress + myOffset;
// invoke function
myFuncPointer(A, B, C);
```

When loading a DLL you load it using LoadLibrary, then use GetProcAddress and typecast the address returned to your function pointer -- i.e. `myFuncPointer = (myFunc)GetProcAddress(hmodule, "myFunc");` in the example.

On POSIX it works pretty much the same, but the functions are slightly different: use `dlopen` to load the dynamic library, and `dlsym` to retrieve the symbol. The [Programming Library Howto](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO.html#DL-LIBRARIES) describes this in more detail, or see the man pages for [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) and [dlsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym). The basics are the same.

Comment: +1 for an excellent example, if you are familiar with posix you should update your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
( (void(*)(A*,B,C))0x42 )(a,b,c);
```

Or something like that. Always had troubles getting that at the first time. That is if I understand your question right, anyway.